# How to config next.js to support css file in amp mode?

Tags: css, webpack, amp-html, next.js

By default next.js create a external file and push css to it. But amp only support inline style. How to config next.js to support css (tailwindcss) in amp mode.
Now next.js only support [styled jsx](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx) styling in amp mode by default.
I ask this question in [spectrum.chat community](https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/how-to-config-next-js-to-support-css-in-amp-mode~4a529ec8-3a46-488a-83d6-6b445cb7a77d) before but not get any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write inline CSS on amp pages but I did not see my CSS code on the console. After that, I found a solution. I am sharing code. I hope so, it helps to solve your mistakes.

```
const initialProperty = {
'amp-custom': '',
};

render() {
const styleElement = (
<style jsx {...initialProperty}>
{
`.example-button { color: black; }`
}
</style>
);
}
return (

<React.Fragment>
 {styleElement}
</React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Your solution is right but I want to use css preprocessor (postCss/scss).

Comment: Okay. I understand. I didn't use CSS preprocessor on amp pages. Did you try example {% include "/assets/main.scss" %} in style tag?

Comment: Yes. I want next.js export CSS preprocessor result to in-line styles in output HTML.

Comment: I understand. If you solve the problem please share it with me and if I find a solution, I will share it with you.

Comment: [Next.js 9.2](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-2#built-in-css-module-support-for-component-level-styles) support built-in CSS Module. I think is Okay with amp and solve my problem.